# How do I create a custom 404 error page for a missing Amazon S3 Object

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently using my AWS S3 to store attachments, so I created an s3 bucket for it.  So when I uploaded an attachment and I can view the attachment via the link:

[bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/[object name]

And if I delete that attachment above and then go to the link above, I get the following message:

```
    
    NoSuchKey
    The specified key does not exist.
    test/test.jpg
    [some request id]
    
    [some host id]
```

So I tried to create an html display "Attachment has been deleted".  So what I tried is make the bucket a static website and set the routing rules to redirect to an html page I place in the bucket if the HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals is 404.  But that only works if I tried it using this url:

[bucket].s3-website-us-[region].amazonaws.com/[invalid object name]

If I try using the link below, it doesn't work:

[bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/[invalid object name]

Is there any other way I can redirect to an error html page if the object doesn't exist using the link above ([bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/[invalid object name])?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

It is a big but easy process. I can't give you the solution in detail here. But, I can give you a link that will help you. I have done the same thing that is in the link. If you have any doubts just comment here.

Link: http://blog.celingest.com/en/2013/12/12/cloudfront-configuring-custom-error-pages/

Comment: Helpful! Though, you might want to describe the process a little bit in case the link dies.